# Targeting an ID that is rendered by a script

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm using a nifty little script called Tabifier (http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/)

Now, long story short, this script, which I run in my head tag, creates a `<ul>` with `<li>`s containing `<a>`s. Also in the head tag it creates IDs for these `<a>`s. When I inspect the loaded site I can clearly see the ID tags present. However, I cannot call them using getElementById. I've been using

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('rightpanelnav1').style.padding='200px';    
</script>
```

as a sample script in different parts of my code but to no avail. I'm wondering wether it's the placement or order in which these things are defined in my code that's causing it not to recognize the ID. What do you think?

EDIT: I recieved a great answer below, but I still can't get 'rightpanelnav1' to register onclick events...? It's an , there shouldn't be a problem, right? And when I click it, the entire page has been loaded for several seconds...

Comment: Because `rightpanelnav1` is not present in page when your code runs. Why not using CSS ?

Comment: agreed with @Jashwant... If all you want to do is set the styles for an element, use CSS not Javascript.

Comment: As I wrote, I used that as a sample script, of course I'm not setting styles with JS :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, in order to access an element in the DOM, the element must be a part of the DOM (`document`). So if you place your `<script>` with `getElementById` in the page at a place prior to where the element is loaded, it will not see the element in the DOM.

Secondly, it is highly probable that this library you use does its modification on page load, which would mean that no matter where you place your `<script>` it would have no chance of seeing these elements before running.

As a result, you should have your script wait as well, and do this:

```
window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById('rightpanelnav1').style.padding='200px';
};
```

Or for a click event

```
window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById('rightpanelnav1').onclick = function(){
  alert("clicked!");
 };
};
```

Comment: That certainly did the trick, thanks for a very well written explanation!

Comment: HOWEVER, 'rightpanelnav1' still doesn't register onclick events. When I click it I assume the page has already loaded, so why is this not working?

Comment: @user2162576 - How did you assign the click event? It is possible the framework removed your event because it seems there is a hook for exposing click events.

Comment: document.getElementById('rightpanelnav1').onclick = function(){stuff}

Comment: Is that inside of the `window.onload = function(){}` block?

Comment: No, heh, can I group functions into eachother like that? Trying that now...yeah that made my stuff jump around, weird...Should I just put that inside the moustache brackets of the window.onload function?

Comment: @user2162576 - Yup, nesting functions is just fine. See my edit for the click event.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time with me! Strangely, when I copy and paste that bit of code, all my divs get jumbled up. What is happening? :-(

Comment: @user - The onclick or the padding? Because the padding will definitely affect the layout.

Comment: No, no I removed the padding bit, I just used your code with the onclick alert. It defies all logic but it seems to be putting all my divs on the same z-index, with no overlapping...how is that even possible?

Comment: Actually, it seems to be stopping the page load just before everything is arranged.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26976/discussion-between-user2162576-and-travis-j)